# mongoose \ mongodb sort by some list?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, database

I am working in MEAN STACK application.
I can not make mongoose query in mongoose like as MYSQL Query which is given bellow

```
SELECT _id, username
FROM user
ORDER BY FIELD(_id, "575123d687ed49be12404584", "575123d687ed49be12404587", "572d8b5aab1db7e1160a273a", "575123d687ed49be124045a5")
```

From this I want to get out put in following order using mongoose

```
first document (record) -> 575123d687ed49be12404584  
second document (record) -> 575123d687ed49be12404587  
third document (record) -> 572d8b5aab1db7e1160a273a  
fourth document (record) -> 575123d687ed49be124045a5  
remaining are in ascending order.
```

can any one give me a proper solution to get result in give ORDER BY.

Comment: If you know how  to get this type of out put, Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
user.find({_id : id}).sort({_id : 1}).exec(function(err,result){...});
```

Comment: I know it but I want to sort by given ids first and then others are ascending  not all ascending.

Answer (score 0):

If `User` is the Mongoose Schema then:

```
User
  .find({_id : {$in: [11, 12, 14]}})
  .sort({_id : 1})
  .exec(function(err,result){

  });
```

Comment: I know it but I want to sort by given ids first and then others are ascending  not all ascending.